# Android Mediaplayer adjust volume

Tags: android, media-player, volume, silent

Anyone know how can I increase/decrease the volume of the sound from mediaplayer by clicking on the volume button at the side of the phone? And how can I mute the sound if the phone was set to silent mode?

Code I'm using:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you might be interested in:

> 1, increase/decrease the volume of the sound:
>   [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742174/controlling-volume-in-mediaplayer)

Basically `Override` the `onKeyDown` and then call `mp.setVolumn(float leftVolume,float rightVolume);`

> 2, mute the sound if the phone was set to silent mode

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        mp.setVolume(0,0);
        break;
｝
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is in your mediaPlayer to set

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```