# Change Sound of media player in android

Tags: android

Change Sound of media player in android

I am trying to change sound of media player. Default sound in beep now wants to change the beep sound. I have checked `AudioManager` property but not change.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4179507/1168654

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be interested in:

1, increase/decrease the volume of the sound: [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742174/controlling-volume-in-mediaplayer)

Basically Override the onKeyDown and then call mp.setVolumn(float leftVolume,float rightVolume);

2, mute the sound if the phone was set to silent mode

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        mp.setVolumn(0,0);
        break;
｝
```