# Android: MediaPlayer setVolume function not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play sound via media player on STREAM_SYSTEM

using

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f , 1.0f);
```

or

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.90f , 0.90f);
```

But it is playing on vol as per Hardware volume controls in settings.

Basically this line has no effect.

I have added

```
permissions "Modify..." as well in Manifest
```

But i saw links in stackoverflow where this API works.

I don't wanna go to API

```
AudioManager.setStreamVol()....
```

as it sets stream vol for all apps

What is problem that this setVol API is not working??

Can anybody give a link to working sample??

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215459/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function help this?

Comment: @Karthikeyan thanks.But i have been through this link.I am using the same

Comment: Is any error or Warning messaging displaying in logcat. If yes, can you post it.

Comment: No error and no warnings...can you give me any working sample using setVolumeAPI MediaPlayer   
Thanks

Comment: assign the StreamVolume to control the mediaplayer volume along with profile volume of that type

Comment: @santhosh Then there is no use of setVolumeAPI of MediaPlayer , i can do the same via using API of AudioManager.

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue. I thought that if I use 0.5f as parameter, I could tell the difference. I tried 0.2f, still no difference. So I thought there was a problem indeed. I finally tried 0.02f just in case, and finally I had a lower volume.

**Sample:**

replace your

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.90f , 0.90f);
```

with

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.09f , 0.09f);
```

Comment: you can also divide the current stream volume by `15f` like: `float volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) / 15f;` and then `mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);`

Answer (score 2):

You must put the volume value between 0.0f and 1.0f. So 1.0f is 100% of the volume. Because of that your line has not effect.

Comment: I have tried .98f as well , but it still sounds as same vol as of STREAM_SYSTEM.If it is mute then no sound in played by player

Comment: Try to do like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742174/controlling-volume-in-mediaplayer

Comment: Maybe it's missing <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioManager audioManager;
int actualVolume;
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
actualVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, actualVolume + 1, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

The above code is taken from my working project, where it is used to increase the volume of the system (I used it for TV). You can use `actualVolume - 1` to lower down the volume.