# Android MediaPlayer setVolume not working properly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

when i use the function setVolume(left,right) the volume of the song is affected just by left volume, right can be whatever number, mp just does not care. The volume changes correctly on both ears, just following the left one.

here are pieces of code

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(ZenActivity.appContext, resID);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.setVolume(stream_volL, stream_volR);
mp.start();
```

```
vol_downR.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
            private Handler mHandler;
            Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    stream_volR= Math.max(0f,stream_volR-0.0025f);
                    mp.setVolume(stream_volL,stream_volR);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                }
            };
```

i looked at all(?) the posts about setVolume but no one seems to have my same problem, either the function does not work completely or they have other issues; in any way their solutions did not work for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it, the files that i was trying to play were mono, so i used audacity and make them stereo by duplicating the track

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The subtracted amount 0.0025 is much too small to hear a difference in loudness, see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087497/android-mediaplayer-setvolume-function-not-working). Increase this amount, and most likely the program will work.

Comment: i tryed with biggest amount, nothing changed. the question you mention says that the guy was trying with a big amount, the best answer says to try with a small one, so cant be right what you are saying. and in any case, my setVolume works, it just works on both ears using volume of left ear and ignoring the right one. seems it acts like mono and not stereo